# How to set infix & prefix indexing in sphinx search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I want to have infix indexing for few fields and prefix indexing for some other fields in my table. Is there a way to do it in sphinx?

I'm looking for options `infix_fields & prefix_fields` in Sphinx with  `dict=keywords`

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can set it per field in the index definition:

```
indexes name, :infixes => true
indexes location, :prefixes => true
```

The dict setting can only be set per-index, so if you want it for specific indices, add this to those index definitions:

```
set_property :dict => ‘keywords’
```

Or for all indices, add it to each environment in your `config/thinking_sphinx.yml` file:

```
development:
  dict: keywords
test:
  dict: keywords
production:
  dict: keywords
```

Though at some point, I believe keywords will be (if it isn’t already) the default dict setting for Sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ThinkingSphinx::Index.define(:incident, DEFAULT_INDEX_OPTIONS.merge(name: "incident_#{i}"), &Searchable.beetilable_index('Incident', index_count: incident_index_count, index_id: i) {
    indexes name
    set_property :min_prefix_len => 3
  })

  #
  # infix index (only for the title, symptom columns)
  #
  ThinkingSphinx::Index.define(:incident, DEFAULT_INDEX_OPTIONS.merge(name: "incident_#{i + incident_index_count + 1}"), &Searchable.beetilable_infix_index('Incident', index_count: incident_index_count, index_id: i) {
    indexes location
    set_property :min_infix_len => 3
  })
end
```